# Connection Closed Gracefully on IOHandler.ReadLn Solution at IdTcpClient

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

I have a small problem, when connect to server TIdTcpClient generate "Connection Closed Gracefully" error on `FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn` of `procedure TReadingThread.Execute;`, that don't happen all time, just some, and if try again and again it don't happen, also don't happen at another VPS where server run. but that's ok.

I did few changes who work arount the error and if error happens it basically disconnect, terminate threads and try again. my question is, what i did can cause some problem or works fine? on tests solved, it failed 8 times and at 9 attempt it connected.

What i did:

```
procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
var
  Recebeu   : String;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try
      Recebeu := FConn.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        THD.Terminate;

        FConn.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        FConn.Disconnect(False);

        if rt <> nil then rt.Terminate;

        THD := TThreadCon.Create;
        THD.Start;
      end;
    end;

    if not Recebeu.IsEmpty then
    begin
```

THD is `THD : TThreadCon = nil`

```
procedure TThreadCon.Execute;
var
  Attempt : Integer;
begin
  Attempt   := 0;

  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if TCPClient.IOHandler <> nil then TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;

      try
        Inc(Attempt);

        TCPClient.Connect;

        try
          TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connect');
        except
          TCPClient.Disconnect(False);
          raise;
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          if (Attempt >= 3) then
          begin
            THD.Terminate;
          end;

          if FTermEvent.WaitFor(2500) <> wrTimeout then Exit;
          Continue;
        end;
      end;

      rt := TReadingThread.Create(TCPClient);
      try
        try
          while not Terminated do
          begin
            if FTermEvent.WaitFor(5000) <> wrTimeout then Exit;
          end;
        except
        end;
      finally
        rt.Terminate;
        try
          TCPClient.Disconnect(False);
        finally
          rt.WaitFor;
          rt.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As i see, since i declare and Set Attempt at Execute, it never will trigger `if (Attempt >= 3) then`on `on E: Exception do` but that's ok.

Connection Closed Gracefully error happens only if Server closes the connection?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection Closed Gracefully" means the connection was closed intentionally by a remote peer, *typically* the server yes, but it could also happen if a firewall/router sitting between the client and server closed the connection due to inactivity, etc.

The error is normal on the client side, and your solution is basically correct - close the connection and reconnect.

Although, I do question why you are calling `Connect()` and `ReadLn()` in separate threads. That is unusual. Why not call them in a single thread instead? You can have an outer loop that calls `Connect()` and `WriteLn()`, and then an inner loop that calls `ReadLn()`, eg:

```
procedure TThreadCon.Execute;
var
  Attempt, ConnectDelay : Integer;
  Recebeu : String;
begin
  Attempt := 0;
  ConnectDelay := 0;

  try
    while (not Terminated) and
          (FTermEvent.WaitFor(ConnectDelay) = wrTimeout) do
    begin
      if TCPClient.IOHandler <> nil then
        TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;

      try
        Inc(Attempt);

        TCPClient.Connect;

        try
          TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connect');
        except
          TCPClient.Disconnect(False);
          raise;
        end;
      except
        if (Attempt >= 3) then Terminate;
        ConnectDelay := 2500;
        Continue;
      end;

      try
        ConnectDelay := 0;

        while (not Terminated) and
              (FTermEvent.WaitFor(0) = wrTimeout) do
        begin
          try
            Recebeu := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 1000);
            if (not TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedOut) and (Recebeu <> '') then
            begin
              ...
            end;
            ...
          except
            ...
            Break;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        TCPClient.Disconnect(False);
        Attempt := 0;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadCon.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTermEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

Comment: declaration of FTermEvent?

Comment: need declare something else? bcs stuck at (FTermEvent.WaitFor(0) = wrTimeout) do

Comment: @DouglasRuiz `FTermEvent` is obviously a data member of the `TThreadCon` class in the OP's code. But to answer your question, it would need to be a [`TEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent) object created in the thread's constructor. It can be signaled in an overridden [`TerminatedSet()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.TerminatedSet) method, which is called when the thread's `Terminate()` method sets the `Terminated` property to true.

Comment: At your solution how send "Ping" writeln every X seconds and also receive on same thread?

Comment: can i use "TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('Ping');
          if FTermEvent.WaitFor(2500) = wrSignaled then Exit;"  after "except
            on E: Exception do
            begin
              ...
            end;
          end;"?

Comment: @DouglasRuiz the whole point of the `try..except` is error handling. If an error occurs, it's likely too late to write anything to the socket. Best to just disconnect and reconnect. As for pinging, there is a timeout being used on the reading, so simply do the write in between two reads whenever needed. Use a `TStopWatch` or similar mechanism to know when to do a write after each read is finished.

Comment: Final question, your solution to use only one thread how reconnect to server on same thread if some exception happens on try except of ReadLn? because if it fail (close connection for example) it don't reconnect.

Comment: @DouglasRuiz As I explained in my answer, there is 2 loops. The 1st loop connects, then the 2nd loop reads until terminated or errors, then disconnects. If not terminated then it goes back to the 1st loop to reconnect and then back to the 2nd loop to read, and so on. The `try..except` on reading will stop the 2nd loop, not the 1st loop.

Comment: Can i use following code?
if TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0) then
            begin
              Recebeu := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 5000);
              if (not TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLnTimedOut) and (Recebeu <> '') then
              begin
               ...
              end;
            end
            else
            begin
              TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('Ping');
            end;

or are wrong? i mean for prevent "send" while "receiving" something.

Comment: @DouglasRuiz that code will send endless `Ping`s in a tight loop while there is nothing to read yet. It would not make sense to use a 0-second timeout on `CheckForDataOnSource()` in this situation. The whole point is to make the thread sleep when it has nothing to do. Otherwise, at least use a [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) or [Waitable Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) to delay each `Ping` between loop iterations.

Comment: Removed ping from same code and added on a thread who send every 5 seconds, it can cause some problem if server ask  something for connection or send something?